# How to get distinct values from JSON object property for dropdown options using ng-options and use it as a filter?

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to make a multiple selection list with a dropdown above it as a filter. The value of the dropdown above contains the department name that will then display its employees in the list below according to the selected department above.

Here is my scope:

```
var self = this;
 self.users = [{ department: "A", name: "santos" }, { department: "B", name: "suarez" }, { department: "C", name: "domingo" }, { department: "A", name: "james" }, { department: "B", name: "black" }, { department: "C", name: "de leon" }, { department: "A", name: "dela cruz" }, { department: "B", name: "robertson" }, { department: "C", name: "williams" }, { department: "A", name: "crawford" },
 { department: "B", name: "garcia" }, { department: "C", name: "navarro" }, { department: "A", name: "lim" }, { department: "B", name: "lee" }, { department: "C", name: "vasquez" }, { department: "A", name: "montano" }, { department: "B", name: "trump" }, { department: "C", name: "arroyo" }, { department: "A", name: "aquino" }, { department: "B", name: "duterte" }];
```

and here is my html:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-options="item as item.department for item in formsDcfCtrl.users" ng-model="departmentsList">
 <option value="" selected>Departments</option>
 </select>

<select multiple class="form-control" ng-options="x as x.name for x in formsDcfCtrl.users | filter:departmentsList" ng-model="usersList"></select>
```

but I get different results:

the value of the list below is fine but the values of the dropdownlist is based from each of the values of the departments in the array:

[image]

and when I select a letter(department) from the dropdown, instead of *ALL* the names that are in department A, for example, will be showed in the list below, only the name whose specific value of department in that specific element in the selected dropdown value is displayed. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with the below mentioned **filter** to get it resolved. Also check your given example working scenario with this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/D2nzh2Nnovpif6es5CWb?p=preview) link.

**Template:**

```
ng-options="item as item.department for item in users | unique:'department'"
```

**Controller:**

```
app.filter('unique', function() {
    return function(input, key) {
        var unique = {};
        var uniqueList = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
            if(typeof unique[input[i][key]] == "undefined"){
                unique[input[i][key]] = "";
                uniqueList.push(input[i]);
            }
        }
        return uniqueList;
    };
});
```

Comment: ok the unique filter works but when I select a value (A, B, C), not all the names in department is displayed.

Comment: For that you should consider the department to be filtered in the multi-select users drop-down which I've made the correction with the same [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/D2nzh2Nnovpif6es5CWb?p=preview). Please check..

Comment: oh thank you it works. So I am only missing the ".department" in my filter?

Comment: Yeah right. Since you are considering model value to be filtered rather you should give the exact value to get filtered by mentioning the key from that object.

Comment: I just didn't know you can do that. I am new to Angular. thanks

Comment: Oh Fine. If you think you got the expected answer with explanation then give up-vote and Mark as answer :) Cheers..